# I couldn't comment on your site because my rating was below 50

Tags: support, comments, reputation

I am new to technology and I have never commented before. This strange form of discrimination seems a little unfair for those of us who don't spend their lives glued to social media. Please help a newbie. How do I raise my "whatever it is" score?

Comment: [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)

Answer (score 5):

The way the Stack Exchange (SE) system (that Literature, this website, is a part of) works, [commenting on other people's posts is a privilege](https://literature.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment), awarded when a user reaches 50 [reputation](https://literature.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) points. One of the reasons for this is keeping the comments constructive: SE is by no means a social media, and reputation is at least partly intended to be a measure of a user's familiarity with the system.

Comments are intended for asking for clarifications on questions and giving constructive feedback on answers - those two are the main features of the SE system, around which everything else resolves. Comments are supposed to be temporary and certainly not chatty. Note that a user can leave comments on own posts regardless of their reputation score.

A chattier and more social part of the SE network is [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=literature.stackexchange.com) - one only needs 15 reputation points to join it.

As to raising your reputation score, there are basically two ways: asking questions and posting answers. An upvote on a question will bring you 5 points, an upvote on an answer will bring you 10 points. A few good questions or answers will quickly allow you to comment on any post.

Comment: Correction: you can join a chat room even on 1 rep, but [participating needs 20 rep](https://literature.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat) (feel free to delete this comment if it has been incorporated to the post :)